# Convert BTC unit and reverse it

Tags: javascript, currency, bitcoin, converters

For example, my user have following balance:

```
0.0022918 BTC
```

Now i want to make this amount like this:

```
2,291.80 BIT
```

So, i use this function:

```
function bitConvert(value) {
    var number = value * 100000000;
    return (number/100).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}
```

Everything is good and i dont have problem.

But I dont know how can i do this opposite?

Convert `2,291.80` BIT to `0.0022918` BTC

**How Can I do this ?**

And I also want a solution for addition and subtraction BTC.

Comment: Don't try to convert it back and forth. Just store one single numeric value, and format it as needed when you want to display it.

Comment: I don't know how can do this. can show me example ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you have a string containing your value in BIT.

You have first to remove all the thousands separators (`,`), then to convert your string to a number. Finally, you have to return the resulting number (keeping a one-sat accuracy) as a string (so use `toString()` method).

Here is the resulting function :

```js
function btcConvert(stringValue) {
    var number = Number(stringValue.replace(',','')) / 100000000;
    return number.toFixed(8).toString();
}
```